# Why Ktor Post Request freeze app, but Get doesn't freeze it?

Tags: kotlin, ktor

```
suspend fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val client = HttpClient(CIO)
    embeddedServer(Netty, 6001) {
        routing {
            get("/") {
                println(call.request.toLogString())
                call.respondText("Please use POST method", status = HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
            }
            post("/") {
                call.respondText("{}")
                val params = call.receiveText()
                println(params)
                delay(200)
                println("pre response")
                val response2: HttpResponse = client.post("https://google.com")
                println(response2.status)
                val response: HttpResponse = client.post("https://discord.com/api/webhooks/discord/webhookurl") {
                    body = "{\"content\": \"$params\"}"
                }
                println("after")
                println("response: ${response.receive<String>()}")
            }
        }
    }.start(true)
}
```

This code print to console:

```
{"test":"test"}
pre response
```

and app freezed.
If I attempt to send GET requests to google or discord, this working and don't freezing.
Why?

Comment: I've got `ClientRequestException: Client request(https://google.com/) invalid: 405 Method Not Allowed` after `pre response`. If I set `expectSuccess` to `false` for the client then an app just prints: `{"test":"test"}\n
pre response\n
405 Method Not Allowed\n
after\n
response: {"webhook_id": ["Value \"discord\" is not snowflake."]}\n`

Comment: What you see in your server logs? Please add logs by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68805169/edit) your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Post request to google.com throws an exception:

```kotlin
client.post("https://google.com")
```

If you see this warning in your logs:

```
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
```

Then you should add [slf4j](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple) dependency to your project to enable logging:

```
implementation("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:(version)")
```

After that you will see full stacktrace of your error in your server logs:

```
[eventLoopGroupProxy-4-1] ERROR ktor.application - Unhandled: POST - /
    io.ktor.client.features.ClientRequestException:
        Client request(https://google.com/) invalid: 405 Method Not Allowed.
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: If this is an answer to your question, then you may [mark](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) the answer as "accepted".